# Line-based 3D modeler (alternative to Sketchup)

Tags: linux, open-source, 3d, cad, file-format

I have seen plenty of parametric 3D CAD applications, like freecad and Autodesk, but only one that is line-based (Sketchup) and thus can easily edit STL files. Are there any other line-based 3D modelers like Sketchup.

It would be nice if it could run on Linux. (natively; I do not prefer online applications.)
I also would prefer not to have to create an account.
Mac-only software will not work.

Comment: Have you looked at Onshape?  It's web based so runs on any computer.

Comment: @EricShain Thanks for your suggestion, but I meant native applications. I have edited my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Blender will read in STL files I believe - just checked on the [Blender.org](https://blender.org) page, and yes, it does:

Alembic, 3D Studio (3DS), COLLADA (DAE), Filmbox (FBX), Autodesk (DXF), Wavefront (OBJ), DirectX (x), Lightwave (LWO), Motion Capture (BVH), SVG, Stanford PLY, STL, VRML, VRML97, X3D

Are all import/export supported in the latest Blender.